# How do I add TESSERACT_PATH to my environment?

Tags: linux, unix, path, cygwin

I am very new to the linux/unix command line and I am having some difficulty with cygwin.

I have a set of src files that I want to build and I also have the ndk files in a different directory (none of the paths have spaces in the names)

Every time I navigate to my source files and type the full path to my ndk-build file it says

> You must set the TESSERACT_PATH variable to the Tesseract source 
>   directory.

Please could someone help me in doing this?

Comment: When you say that you have files you want to build, what language are we talking about: c, c++, Java, etc?

Comment: its jni calls so i assume that is in c? http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the `bash%` prompt, you could type

```
export TESSERACT_PATH=/home/SkyR/path/to/tesseract/src
```

Or you could edit your /home/SkyR/.profile file to add that same line, so that it would be available all the time.

Comment: i did the first approach, hit enter, no feedback so i assume something happened, yet when i proceed to then build the files i get exactly the same error again :(

Comment: Alternatively, if the path is not under the cygwin installation folder, but in other Windows folder you may need to write it like: `/cygdrive/c/path/to/my/folder/`

Comment: ahhh ok this is working now. although its now asking me for other path variables for which i have no idea of the location :D

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an [environment variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Environment) that you need to set in your shell. If so, you can set it on the command line or in your ~/.bashrc with:

```
export TESSERACT_PATH=/path/to/tesseract/source
```

Comment: If set only in `~/.bashrc` it will be required that the user `source ./.bashrc`, right?

Comment: It is generally sourced by interactive shells, so you shouldn't have to do it manually. But if it doesn't work "out of the box," you may want to reference http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html for a deeper understanding of startup file processing.